# Sort Java Objects Alphabetically to a JSON Object

Tags: java, json, sorting, for-loop, alphabetical

Hello i hope someone can help,i wish to sort this list alphabetically into this json object
but im having a bit of trouble with the logic.I was using a compareTo method as below but cant seem to get it to work(have tried a few different ways ,Thank you in advance to anyone who can help

```
      JSONObject practiceDetailsJson = new JSONObject();
         for (Practice practice : practices) {
            practice.getPracticeName().compareTo(obj2.getName());
            practiceDetailsJson.put("practiceName", practice.getPracticeName());
            practiceDetailsJson.put("practiceCode", practice.getPracticeCode());
            practiceDetailsJson.put("practiceId", practice.getRowid());
            practicesAsJSON.add(practiceDetailsJson);
            }
        }
```

Comment: "cant seem to get it to work". what is obj2 and what are you expecting to achieve when calling compareTo inside of the for loop that adds your array into the JSONObject?

Comment: im looking to compare alphabetically the first and second objects in Practice to see which is first,maybe you can suggest another way?

Comment: are you looking to sort an array of objects? Maybe you should call sort() after implementing [Comparator](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) for the Practice class

Comment: @Maria88 read [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html) how to sort `List` obejcts. you need to either implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` interface and iterate through the `List` to make `JSON` list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a comparator here.

```
class PracticeComparator implements Comparator<Practice> {
           @Override
           public int compare(Practice p1, Practice p2) {

                return p1.getPracticeName().compareTo(p2.getPracticeName());
           }
}
```

You can use this comparator like:-

```
Collections.sort(practices, new PracticeComparator());
```

Now you can again iterate over practices to convert it to JSON format.